# Python - OS Module 'TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable''

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

I Was trying to make a checker with the OS module for the directory lib, and it raised a error, the full error log is

> ```
> for folder in path.exists('./lib'):
> ```
>
> TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

the code is

```
for folder in path.exists('./lib'):
    if folder == False:
        print("lib folder not found, please re-install the repository.")
        if folder.isfile == True:
            print("Found a file called 'lib' and not the directory. Please re-install the repository")
            quit()
        else:
            pass
    else:
        print("Found.")
```

i don't know what's the problem, i tried changing it multiple times but i don't know any solutions. but the rest of the code that i have is working without any errors.

Comment: `path.exists` returns a boolean object

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM, yea, i know, but how can i make it so it check's if it's there or not

Comment: Well, as the error suggests, `os.exists` simply returns `True`/`False` if the file exists or not. What do you mean to do by iterating over that result?

Comment: You don't need a loop here... Just replace `if folder == False` with `if path.exists('./lib') == False`

Comment: Something in the logic doesn't add-up... You're trying to check if lib is a file, after the check that it exists failed... I think you want a structure like `if path.exists(...); elif path.isfile(...): else:`

Comment: @Tomerikoo who know's that the lib folder is actually a file. (Im just adding a few checks, if it dosent have a lib folder, it check if there's a file called lib

Comment: what is `path` in your code?

Comment: @Tomerikoo i used `from os import path`

Comment: You should show that in your code. We need a [mre] to help effectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path.exists()` just returns `True` or `False` depending on if that path exists. You should first check its existence via `exists()`, then use `os.listdir()` or `glob.glob()` to actually get a list of items in that path, but only if `exists()` returned `True`.